# Iterating through an array of objects to get the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I made an http request to pull a column of data from a table. I'm having an issue trying to iterate through and array of objects inside of an object at the moment after pulling this data. I tried converting the object into an array with `Array.from()` and `split()`, but that returns each character inside the object separated by a space. How can I iterate through this array of objects inside of the main object to get the value of each key field named "value"?

Here's the object I pulled with my request:

```
0: "{"
data ":[{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
644 Lucon Road Back Warehouse, Schwenksville, North Dakota 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
5689 Henkels Lane Suite 504, Annapolis Junction, New Jersey 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
2563 Dickerson Pike Suite 105, Nashville, North Dakota 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
123 Country Lane, Prosperity, North Dakota 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
896 Cember Way Suite A, Summerville, North Carolina 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
1125 NW 97 th Avenue, Doral, Texas 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
896 Hill Avenue Suite C, Toledo, Alabama 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
2101 Pleasant Valley Lane Suite B, Arlington, Texas 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
1000 S Marietta Parkway SE Suite 105, Marietta, Timbuktu 35896 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
1258 103 rd Street Suite 127, Jacksonville, Texas 35896 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
9856 Corporate Drive North Suite 201, Mobile, Maryland 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
9563 Leah Drive Unit 1, Hillsborough, North Dakota 25896 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
5689 Brookshire Road Unit D, Greer, North Dakota 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
1587 Kessler Avenue Suite 301, Schulenburg, Arizona 58963 "}},{"
8 ":{"
value ":"
fields ":[{"
id ":8,"
label ":"
Address ","
type ":"
address "}],"
metadata ":{"
numFields ":1,"
numRecords ":15,"
skip ":0,"
totalRecords ":15}}"
```

Here's my request:

```
 const headers = {
            'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'xxxxx.quickbase.com',
            'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        const body = {
            "from": "bn6rb5ll9",
            "select": [8],
            "options": {
                "skip": 0,
                "top": 0
            }
        }

        const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open('POST', 'https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', true);
        for (const key in headers) {
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
        }
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                let jsonObject = xmlHttp.responseText.split();
                console.log(jsonObject);
                // for (let i = 0; i <= jsonObject.length; i++) {
                //     console.log((jsonObject[i]));
                // }
                // const propValues = Object.values(xmlHttp.responseText);
                // console.log(propValues);
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```

This is the response I get if I use `Array.from(xmlHttpResponseText)`

```
(1242) ["{", """, "d", "a", "t", "a", """, ":", "[", "{", """, "8", """, ":", "{", """, "v", "a", "l", "u", "e", """, ":", """, "2", "0", "3", "3", " ", "L", "u", "c", "o", "n", " ", "R", "o", "a", "d", " ", "B", "a", "c", "k", " ", "W", "a", "r", "e", "h", "o", "u", "s", "e", ",", " ", "S", "c", "h", "w", "e", "n", "k", "s", "v", "i", "l", "l", "e", ",", " ", "P", "e", "n", "n", "s", "y", "l", "v", "a", "n", "i", "a", " ", "1", "9", "4", "7", "3", """, "}", "}", ",", "{", """, "8", """, ":", "{", """, …]
```

I used JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText) and I did manage to get a typeof Array, but I don't see any array methods available to use on that array.[image: Image of return]

Comment: That is not a valid object representation.

Comment: Please post compilable data. Currently, it's unreadable

Comment: `split()` or `Array.from` is definitely wrong. You should do `JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText)` instead when the response is a JSON string, but your object representation at the top is not valid, ... so clarify that.

Comment: if that is your response then your response from that API is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, your payload is not a valid format, so I'll take the text you get from Array.from(xmlHttpResponseText) as a basis.

First, if your payload is JSON you must process it as json and not lines of text:

```
let jsonObject = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

Second, from the data I guess what you are trying to do is extract addresses from the structure. We'll use Array.map to iterate over every entry of data, and extract the property 8.value :

```
const addresses=jsonObject.data.map(e=>e["8"].value);
```

You'll then get an array of strings, which are your addresses, which you can log on the console, or do whatever you want with :

```
console.log(addresses);
```